# VB.Net/Word Access HtmlElement with Webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I am currently working on a Word Addin. From the ribbon, I launch the webbrowser control. If the latter is already open, I would like to modify the content of a text box and simulate a button click. Problem is, I have a NullPointerException when I try to access the textbox. I have seem some similar questions but none of the solutions are working for me. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles btn.Click

    Dim frame As New frm_browser()
    Dim search As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim WordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = frame.browser.Document
    Dim htmlSearchField As HtmlElement
    Dim htmlSearchButton As HtmlElement

    search = WordApp.Selection.Text

    If IsFormOpen(browser.GetType()) = False Then
        frame.Show()
        url = "http://example.com?search=" + search
        frame.browser.Navigate(url)
    Else
        'Trigger the error and the htmlElement returns null
        htmlSearchField = doc.GetElementById("tb_id")
        htmlSearchField.SetAttribute("value", search)
        htmlSearchButton = doc.GetElementById("btn_id")
        htmlSearchButton.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is the html parts that I try to access:

```
<input id="tb_id" name="xxx" type="text" value="">
<div id="btn_id">Contains an image that simulate a search button</div>
```

Any hint would bw appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I *think* the problem comes from you doing `Dim frame As New frm_browser()` when the button is clicked. So any existing, open control isn't accessible at this point. Perhaps you need a class-level object for an instance of `frm_browser`? Then you can check if it's set to `Nothing`. If yes, create a new one, if no work with the class-level member.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you so much ! Problem solved ! =D Indeed, the frame needed to be a class-level object.